# Add Active Class for any URL match to first segment?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Javascript is adding the active class to all links with one segment that match my path variable, but not ones with two on my nav.

I want it regardless to check the first segment of any URL that is currently in the window.location.pathname and if the first segment matches then add the active class to the nav item.

It works for home, products and gallery. But when I console.log(linkPath) it's showing for the url **products/samples** the text sample and not products. Thus there is no math and it will not add the active class to the current item.

How Can I get it to add the active class no matter what based off the first segment matching within any url with more than one segment?

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <h2 class="markup">Main Navigation</h2>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-nav-list navbar-link-background">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/products">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/promotions">Promotions</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.example.com/products/samples">Samples</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Javascript

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split( '/' ),

path = url[1];

/* Get URL For Setting Active Nav List Item */
$(".navbar-nav").children("li").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).children("a").attr("href"),
        linkPathIndex = link.lastIndexOf("/")+1,
        linkPath = link.substring(linkPathIndex);

    if (linkPath == path) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you check for the pathname directly in the link href? something like this:

```
$(".navbar-nav").children("li").each(function() {
    var link = $(this).children("a").attr("href");
    if(link.indexOf(path) > -1){
       $(this).addClass("active");
       return;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
this.win.on(events.load, function() {
    var anchors = self.list.prev().find(cache.anchor),
        url = document.URL;

    $.each(anchors, function() {
        var anchor = $(this),
            href = anchor.prop('href');

        if (url.indexOf(href) !== -1) {
            anchor.addClass(classes.active);
        }
    });
});
```